# In C++, how do I refer to functions in different header files?

Tags: c++, file, text

I'm trying to create a simple text adventure and I'm splitting the code into multiple headers to make compile time faster and to make it more organized.

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "main_menu.h"
#include "file_select.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 main_menu();
}
```

The Main Menu header file looks like this:

```
\\main_menu.h
#ifndef main_menu_H
#define main_menu_H
#include <iostream>
#include "file_select.h"
using namespace std;
void main_menu() {
cout << string(50,'\n');
cout << "                      ADVENTURE OF THE SKYLANDS                                 \n";
cout << "================================================================================\n";
cout << "                             CHAPTER 1                                          \n";
cout << "================================================================================\n";
cout << "                         Scepter of The Winds                                   \n";
cout << "                               v1.0.0                                           \n";
cout << "================================================================================\n";
char select;
cout << "\n\n\n\n\n"  << "MAIN MENU\n\n";
cout << "1. Start\n";
cout << "2. File Select\n";
cout << "3. Credits\n";
cout << "4. Exit Game\n";
cin >> select;
 if (select == 'S' || select == 's' || select == '1') {

}
else if (select == 'F' || select == 'f' || select == '2') {
    file_select();
}
else if (select == 'C' || select == 'c' || select == '3') {
}
else if (select == 'E' || select == 'e' || select == 'x' || select == 'X' || select == '4') {
    return;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Invalid Option!";
    }
}
#endif
#include
```

Finally, the File Select Menu header file and this is where I'm having an error: "main_menu" was not declared in this scope.

```
#ifndef file_select_H
#define file_select_H
#include <iostream>
#include "main_menu.h"
using namespace std;
void file_select() {
cout << "                       FILE SELECT                                                \n";
cout << "==================================================================================\n";
cout << "1. File 1\n";
cout << "2. File 2\n";
cout << "3. File 3\n";
cout << "4. Return to Main Menu\n";
char fileselect;
cin >> fileselect;
if (fileselect == '1') {
}
else if (fileselect == '2') {
}
else if (fileselect == '3') {
}
else if (fileselect == '4') {
main_menu();
}
else {
    cout << "Invalid Option.";
}
}

#endif
```

Comment: Don't put function *definitions* in header files (unless you declare them as `static` or `inline`). Instead put the definitions in separate source files, and only put *declarations* in the header files.

Comment: And what is your question? What other problem do you have with your code?

Comment: How would I go about fixing my code so it works?  Like how do I refer to a function in let's say Header1.h and want to refer to it in Header2.h

Comment: @LightWriter Like Joachim Pileborg suggested, you should put the [declarations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/declarations) in your header files(xx.h) and [definitions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) in source files(yy.cpp). To use the function declared in other header files, just include that header file(xx.h) in the current source file(yy.cpp).

Answer (score 4):

Generally, header files should only contain *declarations* while CPP files should contain the *definitions* to the declarations. This means that for any declaration, you only provide the return type, function name, and any parameters types followed by a semi-colon. The definition requires that you provide everything in the declaration but also parameter names and all the statements to go inside of the function. Examples are below:

**Declaration Example (Header Files):**

- `void file_select();`
- `void main_menu();`
- `int anotherExample(int);`
- `bool finalExample(char optionalVariableName);`

**Definition Example (CPP Files):**

```
bool finalExample(char optionalVariableName) {
    return (optionalVariableName == '\0');
}
```

That being said, your code should transform into the following:

> main.cpp

```
#include "MainMenu.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    main_menu();
    return 1;
}
```

> MainMenu.h

```
#ifndef MAIN_MENU_H
#define MAIN_MENU_H

#ifndef FILE_SELECT_H
#include "FileSelect.h"
#endif

void main_menu();

#endif
```

> MainMenu.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "MainMenu.h"

using namespace std;

void main_menu() {
    cout << string(50,'\n');
    cout << "                      ADVENTURE OF THE SKYLANDS                                 \n";
    cout << "================================================================================\n";
    cout << "                             CHAPTER 1                                          \n";
    cout << "================================================================================\n";
    cout << "                         Scepter of The Winds                                   \n";
    cout << "                               v1.0.0                                           \n";
    cout << "================================================================================\n";
    char select;
    cout << "\n\n\n\n\n"  << "MAIN MENU\n\n";
    cout << "1. Start\n";
    cout << "2. File Select\n";
    cout << "3. Credits\n";
    cout << "4. Exit Game\n";
    cin >> select;
    if (select == 'S' || select == 's' || select == '1') {

    }
    else if (select == 'F' || select == 'f' || select == '2') {
        file_select();
    }
    else if (select == 'C' || select == 'c' || select == '3') {
    }
    else if (select == 'E' || select == 'e' || select == 'x' || select == 'X' || select == '4') {
        return;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Invalid Option!";
    }
}
```

> FileSelect.h

```
#ifndef FILE_SELECT_H
#define FILE_SELECT_H

#ifndef MAIN_MENU_H
#include "MainMenu.h"
#endif

void file_select();

#endif
```

> FileSelect.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "FileSelect.h"

using namespace std;

void file_select() {
    cout << "                       FILE SELECT                                                \n";
    cout << "==================================================================================\n";
    cout << "1. File 1\n";
    cout << "2. File 2\n";
    cout << "3. File 3\n";
    cout << "4. Return to Main Menu\n";
    char fileselect;
    cin >> fileselect;
    if (fileselect == '1') {
    }
    else if (fileselect == '2') {
    }
    else if (fileselect == '3') {
    }
    else if (fileselect == '4') {
        main_menu();
    }
    else {
        cout << "Invalid Option.";
    }
}
```

Comment: I see just two issues with this code you show, one is minor and is that you don't need to include `"FileSelect.h"` in `"MainMenu.h"`, or the other way around. The other isn't a major issue, but it's important nonetheless, and that is that symbols or names beginning with an underscore and followed by an uppr-case letter are reserved for the implementation (compiler and standard library), you should not use such names.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I'm still getting an error that I have an undefined reference to main_menu() in my main.cpp file

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks for your comment; the header files should not be preceded with an underscore. However, `"FileSelect.h"` contains a reference to `"MainMenu.h"` and vice versa, so the include in each will have to be made in each. Nevertheless, thanks for the update. @LightWriter, are you sure that all the files are the same name (I changed main_menu.h to **MainMenu.h**).